# Magento random redirect loop error on particular pages

Tags: magento, ubuntu, redirect

I have this problem with a magento 1.5 CE installation that creates random issues with error pages that should not appear:

The error is: *This webpage has a redirect loop*  and is generated apparently in a random manner, so that is very difficult to trace and replicate.

Also a very strange behavior is that when I click the first product in a particular category it simply refreshes the page and is not going to that product page.

The website is hosted on a Ubuntu machine. I have recently increased the PHP memory limit to 512M with no effect.

The error log on the server does not trace this error however which is very strange.

The problem is that Google from time to time does log this error and is very bad on ranking and also on customer interaction as users cannot see the pages that are supposed to see.

***Update #1:***

Options in Configuration > Catalog > Catalog are as fallows:

- product URL suffix - .html
- category URL suffix - .html
- use category path for product URL - y
- create permanent redirect for old URL is URL key changed - y

This setting used to work for a long time, but now for some particular reason is no longer working.

***Update #2 (solved this ... apparently does not relate to the redirect loop problem):***

I have deleted the previous error log and now it appears to be logging some strange behavior:

```
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:42 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/public_html/skin/frontend/default/ciss/, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:42 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/error_docs/forbidden.html, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:45 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/public_html/skin/frontend/default/ciss/, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa/epson-expression-home-xp-215-cu-ciss.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:45 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/error_docs/forbidden.html, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa/epson-expression-home-xp-215-cu-ciss.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:48 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/public_html/skin/frontend/default/ciss/, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:48 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/error_docs/forbidden.html, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:50 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/public_html/skin/frontend/default/ciss/, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:46:50 2014] [error] [client 82.76.226.240] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/error_docs/forbidden.html, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/acasa.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:47:08 2014] [error] [client 178.138.97.255] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/public_html/skin/frontend/default/ciss/, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/imprimante-sublimare.html
[Mon Apr 28 12:47:08 2014] [error] [client 178.138.97.255] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/cissmarket.ro/error_docs/forbidden.html, referer: http://www.cissmarket.ro/imprimanta-ciss/imprimante-sublimare.html
```

After hitting F5 one time pages with this error are loading normally. Could this be a server configuration error?

***Update #3***

Here is the mod_rewrite part of .htaccess - apprently it looks just fine.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: may be its related to `.htaccess` file. Check that file for errors or replace that.  Check the `mod_rewrite` part

Comment: The apache errors in Update #2 are due to a broken image link below the sidebar:


`<div class="block block-banner">
    <div class="block-content">
                    <img src="http://www.cissmarket.ro/skin/frontend/default/ciss/" title="" alt="">
            </div>
</div>`